# python, webpage, run a python script in a subdirectory and stay in subdirectory

Tags: python, html

Trying to create a website in python.
A form submits a company name.
The working directory is changed to the company name.
Each company has its own directory with the company name as the directory name.
Run index.py in the new (changed) directory.
Stay in the new directory

Problems:
The form code is repeated then the "companyname/index.py" code is executed.

I want:
The calling form code not to repeat.

```
#!python  
import os
import cgi, cgitb
import datetime
from ClassHTMLTemplate import *   # a class to print html header/footer stuff
path ='C:\wamp64\www\QMS_r1'
tplate = HTMLTemplate()
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
companyNumber = form.getvalue('company')
tplate.header()     # just html header stuff    
print('Company Name:',companyName)
print('</br>Current WD:',os.getcwd())
os.chdir(path+'/'+companyName)
print('</br>New Current WD:',os.getcwd()+'</br>')
tplate.footer()  # just html footer stuff
with open("index.py", "r") as file:
    exec(file.read(), {"__name__": ""})
```

Comment: What do you mean with "form code"?

Comment: There is an HTML form that calls this program. The form supplies the companyName

Comment: And the form's HTML-code is shown or the form content is sent again or what exactly happens?